# How do I remove every other string but strings with "metal" in them in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So, I am making a Steam Trade bot and I need help removing every other item in someone inventory and only showing metal.

e.g 
Array

`["Refined Metal", "Refined Metal", "Reclaimed Metal", "Scrap Metal", "Flare Gun", "Strange Shotgun"]`

I want the code to get rid of other strings that do not have the word "Metal" in them.

I've tried array.filter but i don't think that is the right function to use for what i'm doing

I tried

```
var = ["Refined Metal", "Refined Metal", "Reclaimed Metal", "Scrap Metal", "Flare Gun", "Strange Shotgun"]
var = var(array.filter => "Metal")
```

I'm not sure how to use filter

I expect it to show:
`["Refined Metal", "Refined Metal", "Reclaimed Metal", "Scrap Metal"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's always a capital M, use `filter` and `includes`:

```
const metals = array.filter(e => e.includes("Metal"));
```

If it's either case:

```
const metals = array.filter(e => /metal/i.test(e));
```

Comment: Thank you <3 I will make this thread answered when it lets me :)

Comment: No worries @MatinPlays, always glad to help.